# is there a way to check if a word in a generated list, is inside a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a word in a generated list is inside a text file
I made an anagram generator, and I want to see if the list created by that generator has a real word by checking if it's inside an English dictionary.

```
#input
word = input("Word: ")

#function to generate anagrams of the word
def make_anagram(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        yield word
    else:
        for let in make_anagram(word[1:]):
            for i in range(len(word)):
                yield let[:i] + word[0:1] + let[i:]

#function to check anagrams
def check_if_anagram(word):
    #this is the file with the dictionary
    file = open("english-words-master\words.txt")
    words = file.read()

    #here's where I'm havning trouble
    anagram = list(make_anagram(word))
    if str(anagram) in words and str(anagram) != word:
        print(str(anagram) + " is a real anagram.")
    else:
        print("there is no real anagram for " + word)
    file.close()
```

the second function always returns the else statement.
I'm still a beginner so I don't understand how lists work very well, what's wrong in the check_if_anagram function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the whole list is in the file. For example, if `anagram = ['abc', 'acb']` There you are literally checking:

```
if "['abc', 'acb']" in words
```

Which will most likely never happen...

What you want to do, is check ***each anagram*** from the list:

```py
anagrams = list(make_anagram(word))
for anagram in anagrams:
    if anagram in words and anagram != word:
        print(anagram + " is a real anagram.")
        break
else:
    print("there is no real anagram for " + word)
```